Selenium (Undetected Chrome Driver) unable to connect to browser context in docker
I have built a web-scraping script that uses Selenium with undetected_chromedriver to scrape the web. Running the script on my local machine works fine, but it has connection issues when ran on docker/containerized.
Except, the connection issues are not to the website itself but to localhost on a random port that I am assuming is for chrome driver communication.
Error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=59175): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/2447d84a58ac677fa2a41dc4280bd779/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffff1f336a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
If it doesn't throw these exceptions, the script will just hang/freeze around the chromedriver calls (not initialization of the chrome instance though)
In the container (using top), I see chrome using a low amount of resources and the "chrome_crashpad" process.  Is it possible that chrome is just crashing/freezing?'
Using python3.12 on local, python3.10 on container.
I have seen this thread regarding the same issue but I am not calling driver.close or driver.quit anywhere in my code.
It is not an issue with the website itself because the same error occurs when trying to request other urls.
It is not a network issue because when I exec into the container I can execute wget on a site just fine.
I don't believe it is an undetected_chromedriver issue because when I switch to the standard selenium chromedriver there is still problems.
Relevant Code:
import json
from time import sleep
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class WebDriver:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--incognito")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,1696")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        options.add_argument("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false")

        self.driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

    def get(self, url: str, retries: int = 3):
        for i in range(retries):
            try:
                self.driver.get(url)
                return True
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"[WebDriver] ({i + 1}/{retries}) Error: {e}")
                sleep(3)
        print(f"[WebDriver] Failed to get {url}")
        return False

    def get_page_source(self):
        return self.driver.page_source

    def get_page_json(self):
        json_text = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "pre").text
        return json.loads(json_text)

from webdriver import WebDriver
from queue import Queue
from threading import Lock


class WebDriverPool:
    def __init__(self, pool_size=4):
        self.pool = Queue()
        self.lock = Lock()

        for i in range(pool_size):
            self.pool.put(self.create_driver())

    def get_driver(self) -> WebDriver:
        with self.lock:
            return self.pool.get()

    def return_driver(self, webdriver):
        with self.lock:
            self.pool.put(webdriver)

    def create_driver(self) -> WebDriver:
        return WebDriver()

        print("TESTING1")
        driver0 = WebDriver()
        driver0.get("https://example.com")
        print(driver0.get_page_source())

        print("TESTING2")
        driver1 = self.wd_pool.get_driver()
        driver2 = self.wd_pool.get_driver()
        driver1.get("https://example.com")
        driver2.get("https://example.com")
        print(driver1.get_page_source())
        print(driver2.get_page_source())
        self.wd_pool.return_driver(driver1)
        self.wd_pool.return_driver(driver2)

Dockerfile
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    xvfb 


ENV DISPLAY=:99

WORKDIR /scrape
COPY . ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN chmod +x run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]

Docker entrypoint:
#!/bin/bash
echo "[ENTRYPOINT] Starting Xvfb $DISPLAY"
Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1280x1024x24 & \
    echo "[ENTRYPOINT] main.py $1 $2"
    exec python3 main.py $1 $2


